# Getting java.net.UnknownHostException: in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

When I try to access a URL with getting method getting,

```
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "xyz.aaa.net": No address associated with hostname
```

But I am getting success response in POST MAN. Its been two days but not getting any clue.Changed the Actual URL to xyz.aaa.net due to autorization issue.Sorry for that :

```
Call<Response> call2 = apiInterface.getEmployeeListNew("1190",1008,"true"
                );
        call2.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TaxProResponse> call, Response<Response> response) { }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TaxProResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
            }
        });
```

API Client :

```
class APIClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    static Retrofit getClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();


        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://xyz.aaa.net/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();



        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

APIInterface :

```
@GET("Profile")
Call<Response> getEmployeeListNew(
        @Header("app_id") String app_id,
        @Query("office_id") int office_id,
        @Query("need_only_active") String need_only_active
);
```

whole URL need to be like this with app_id as Header :

```
http://xyz.aaa.net/api/Profile?office_id=1008&need_only_active=true
```

If Any of you has faced this issue before please give some suggetion.
Tried with some other request,It working fine.Provide the permission,

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Its not issue of permission like other questions in Stackoverflow.Tried with there solutions and its not working.

As Asked here is Full Log

```
06-25 12:11:38.143 8450-8450/? I/zygote64: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-25 12:11:38.436 8450-8450/com.journaldev.retrofitintro D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
06-25 12:11:38.495 8450-8469/com.journaldev.retrofitintro D/OkHttp: --> GET http://xyz.aaa.net/api/AMTPProfile?office_id=1008&need_only_active=true http/1.1
    app_id: 1190
06-25 12:11:38.497 8450-8469/com.journaldev.retrofitintro D/OkHttp: --> END GET
06-25 12:11:38.516 8450-8471/com.journaldev.retrofitintro D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
06-25 12:11:38.561 8450-8471/com.journaldev.retrofitintro I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 8e59954, I0be83d0d26
    Build Date                       : 09/22/17
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.21.02.00
    Local Branch                     : O17A
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
06-25 12:11:38.564 8450-8471/com.journaldev.retrofitintro D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8994.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
06-25 12:11:38.581 8450-8471/com.journaldev.retrofitintro I/Adreno: PFP: 0x00000000, ME: 0x00000000
06-25 12:11:38.598 8450-8471/com.journaldev.retrofitintro I/zygote64: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
06-25 12:11:38.602 8450-8471/com.journaldev.retrofitintro I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-25 12:11:38.603 8450-8471/com.journaldev.retrofitintro D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
06-25 12:11:38.622 8450-8471/com.journaldev.retrofitintro D/vndksupport: Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
    Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8994.so from current namespace instead of sphal namespace.
06-25 12:11:41.808 8450-8469/com.journaldev.retrofitintro D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "xyz.aaa.net": No address associated with hostname
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This API link is not working

Comment: are you using a device with a valid wifi that has an internet connection? are you trying to connect to your local computer? try calling the api from another computer and check

Comment: @RutvikBhatt I changed the actual url due to Authorization issue. I mentioned that in question itself

Comment: @Nabil I am using a device with valid wifi not with local computer

Comment: can you show full log and your method call?

Comment: Updated in the questions with full Log

Comment: try calling 'xyz.aaa.net' from you mobile browser. it won't do any good but you'll know if this is accessible.

Comment: Can also be an issue of proxy. Try loading it in device's browser and check.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android/Retrofit: application not communicating through http, only through https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52004687/android-retrofit-application-not-communicating-through-http-only-through-https)

Answer (score -1):

@Override
public void onRequestFailure(RetrofitError errorCode, String errorFrom) {
super.onRequestFailure(errorCode, errorFrom);

```
    try {
        throw (errorCode.getCause());

    } catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {

        DialogManager.showSingleBtnPopup(thisAcivity, new DialogMangerCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onOkClick() {
                // doLogout(" ");

                Intent i = new Intent(thisAcivity, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelClick(View view) {

            }
        }, "Alert!", "Network error,  ", "Ok");

        // unknown host
    } catch (SSLHandshakeException e) {

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1);

        // ssl handshake exception
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1);

        // unknown error
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please read [answer]. In particular, please make sure to provide answers that actually address the question being asked. OP is asking a specific question about their code. An answer that dumps completely different code without any context or explanation isn't very helpful.