# Android/Retrofit: application not communicating through http, only through https

Tags: android, http, https, retrofit

I'm trying to create an Android application that will communicate with a server through http protocol. I'm using Retrofit to send a GET request to the server, but I always receive the following error:

```
java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to http://demo5373349.mockable.io/ not permitted by network security policy
```

While no such issue is present when trying to reach a server through https, I'll be writing the server side as well, and I'm supposed to use http.

Here's the code:

```
private TextView textView;
private EditText editText;
private Button getButton;
private Retrofit retrofit;
private ServerConnection connection;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://demo5373349.mockable.io/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    connection = retrofit.create(ServerConnection.class);

    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    getButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonGET);
    getButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getHandler();
        }
    });

}

private void getHandler(){
    connection.sendGET().enqueue(new Callback<Message>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Message> call, Response<Message> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                textView.setText(response.body().toString());
            }else {
                textView.setText("Server Error");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Message> call, Throwable t) {
            textView.setText("Connection Error");
        }
    });
}
```

And the interface:

```
public interface ServerConnection {
    @GET("./")
    Call<Message> sendGET();
}
```

Comment: post your retrofit code

Comment: Which android version are you using?

Comment: this may help https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-android/issues/1765

Comment: @SamiIkhleaf thank you, it solved my problem!

Comment: Android 9 - [framework-security-changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#framework-security-changes)

Answer (score 5):

Starting in Android 9.0 (SDK 28) use cleartext network communications is disabled by default. See [Android 9.0 (SDK 28) cleartext disabled](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted)

You have several options, in order of security preference:

- Change all network access to use HTTPS.
- Add a network security config file to your project.
- Enable Cleartext support for the app by adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to the application in the manifest.

To add a Network Security File to your project, you need to do two things. You need to add the file specification to the manifest:

```
<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" .../>
```

Secondly, create file res/xml/network_security_config.xml and specify your security desires:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">insecure.example.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```